# Django App Heroku Deployment: App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, django, heroku, procfile

I've been through a lot of possible answers from here to everywhere, and it seems the problem persists.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 295, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (272/272), done.
Writing objects: 100% (295/295), 678.12 KiB | 8.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 295 (delta 114), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mydjangoappblog.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mydjangoappblog.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mydjangoappblog.git'
```

My `Procfile`:

[image: Procfile]

And `gunicorn`:

[image: gunicorn]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: Is your `requirements.txt` file in the root directory of your project? Is it committed, and does the commit you're trying to push include that file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Procfile is not valid

Modify it as following:

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

Comment: That's true, but I don't think it would cause an "app not compatible with buildpack" message.